# Git - how to add/link subfolders into one git-repository directory

Tags: filesystems, symlink, git, hard-link, file-management

Assuming I have a file structure like this:

```
├── Project-1/
│   ├── files/
│   └── special-files/
├── Project-2/
│   ├── files/
│   └── special-files/
└── Project-3/
    ├── files/
    └── special-files/
```

Now I want to create a Git repository, including all the `special-files` folders. If it was files, I could create a hardlink `ln ./Project-1/special-files ./Git-Project/special-files-1` and so on, so I would get:

```
Git-Project/
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── special-files-1/
├── special-files-2/
└── special-files-3/
```

Though hardlinks do not work with folders. Symlinks do not get handled by `git`. **Is there a way to achieve, collecting/linking these folders into a `git` repository-folder?**

Answer (score 0):

You can `mount --bind` your `special-files/` directories into `git-project/special-files-X/`.